# CRM Configuration Migration - Date Format

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When I use the CRM Configuration Migration tool to import configuration data into a CRM organisation it incorrectly decides that the dates in the data.xml import file are in mm/dd/yyyy format (US format) but they are in dd/mm/yyyy format and therefore it imports dates incorrectly or not at all e.g. a date of 01/02/2015 (1st Feb) in data.xml is imported into CRM as 02/01/2015 (2nd Jan), a date of 13/01/2015 (13th Jan) is not imported into CRM as it is an invalid date in US format.

The system locale, location, and formats are all set to United Kingdom on both the CRM server and the SQL Server.  In CRM, in both the system settings and the user settings, formats are set to United Kingdom.

How does CRM Configuration Migration tool decide what format dates in the data.xml import file are in?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately not @Dean. I believe it's a bug in the tool. A workaround is to temporarily change the date formats in both CRM organisations to yyyy/mm/dd, export, import, & finally revert the date format to its original setting

Comment: I have added a 'suggestion' to MS. @Koenigsegg       https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedbackdetail/view/1650961/dynamics-crm-2015-configuration-migration-date-format-assumed-to-be-us-format.      Can you vote it up?

Comment: @Dean Thanks.  I have voted your suggestion up, hopefully the bug will be resolved in future versions of the Config Migration tool